# postgres select where id in array selected from a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question from a postgres noob. I have two tables in postgres. See below for schematic.

```
strains_snps::table
    name::str
    variants_id::int array

variants::table
    id::int
    ref_base::str
```

I want to

```
select variants_id 
from strains_snps 
where strains_snps.name = 'foo'
```

and then use that variants_id (which is an int array) in a follow up query.

```
select * 
from variants 
where id in the_output_from_previous_query
```

Coming from python, I would assign the output of the first query to a variable, and then check for membership of that variable in the second query. But that probably isn't the best way here, and I hope there is some way to get this working as a single query?

**EDIT**

@Sumit suggested using a sub-query. I tried this, but without success.

```
select * from variants 
where id in 
(select variants_id from strains_snps where name = 'BMD1964')
```

The error pgadmin returned was

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 2: where id in 
             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You  
might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 34
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: You can use subquery for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
select * 
from variants 
where id in (
    select unnest(variants_id) 
    from strains_snps 
    where strains_snps.name = 'foo' 
)
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks very much!

Comment: And if I have subquery extracted into WITH area?

Comment: can we not use @> or <@

Answer (score 0):

And if you want it separated using WITH statement:

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT UNNEST(variants_id) 
  FROM strains_snps
  WHERE strains_snps.name = 'foo' )
SELECT *
FROM variants
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM ids);
```